# Firestore collections intersection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am implementing the typical followers/following/friends + feed system. For each user in my database, I have 3 subcollections: "followers", "following" and "friends". Currently, I am trying to implement a feed following these three business rules:

1. Feeds are **order by date**.
2. User A can be in the friends list of User B **while user B is not in User A friends list.**
3. You can see the posts of those users you **follow** who also **follow you** or/and **have you scheduled on their friends list.**

In my case, what I have thought to do is to perform multiple reads in a Cloud Function, because it seems not really easy to achieve the third rule... but now I wonder if it would be possible to make a query of this style (similar):

```
 currentUserFollowingRef = db.collection(...).doc(userId).collection("following")
 otherUserFollowingRef = db.collection(...).doc(otherUserId).collection("following")
 otherUserFriendsRef = db.collection(...).doc(otherUserId).collection("friends")
 
  // Some kind of intersection using queries (Pseudo)
 U1 = currentUserFollowingRef.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", otherUserFollowingRef)
                             .limit(10).get();

 // Other intersection
 U2 = currentUserFollowingRef.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", otherUserFriendsRef)
                             .limit(10).get();


 // Union of two sets using pure js
 UFinal = U1 union U2 (using js)

 /* Last step is to retrieve the last post of each user ordered by date using collection group queries */
```

Someone knows how to achieve this doing something similar (retrieving docs which
also are in other collection)?

Any consideration that should be taken into account?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't supported by Firestore.  A query can only consider documents in a single collection at a time.  It's not possible to "join" with documents in other collections.  You will have to do exactly what you said in the question - "perform multiple reads in a Cloud Function" and merge the results of those queries in your code.

Either that, or duplicate data into a new collection that effectively "pre-joins" the data from other collections for a single query.  But that might be a lot of work for this case.

Comment: I have tried to go on with the first approach and seems more expensive and inefficient than the second one. What I will do is to create a root collection "feeds" (your second recommendation) in which, for each user, I will add a subcollection which contains documents with the other user id that are created/removed by a cloud function (that runs the business logic) when pressing the "follow/unfollow/add friend/remove friend" buttons.